# How to combine multiple character columns into one columns and remove NA without knowing column numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to have a column that contains other columns characters without NA.
I have tried `paste`, `str_c` and `unite`, but could not get the expected result. Maybe I used them incorrectly.

The real case is, I could not know the column numbers in advance since each dataset can be varied in terms of years.

i.e. some datasets contain 10 years, but some contain 20 years.

Here is the input data:

```
input <- tibble(
  id = c('aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'qq'),
  '2017' = c('tv', NA, NA, 'web'),
  '2018' = c(NA, 'web', NA, NA),
  '2019' = c(NA, NA, 'book', 'tv')
)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  id    `2017` `2018` `2019`
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 aa    tv     NA     NA    
2 ss    NA     web    NA    
3 dd    NA     NA     book  
4 qq    web    NA     tv
```

The desired output with the ALL column is:

```
> output
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  id    `2017` `2018` `2019` ALL   
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 aa    tv     NA     NA     tv    
2 ss    NA     web    NA     web   
3 dd    NA     NA     book   book  
4 qq    web    NA     tv     web tv
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have updated the context, this might be not the duplicated question.

Comment: My commented advice from the suggested duplicate still stands I reckon. Work with a long dataset with `id / year / value` (use `gather` to convert this set), which you can then easily apply a `group_by` and `paste` against to get what you want. It will be a much clearer structure and avoids the multitudes of `NA` values.

Comment: E.g. - `input %>% gather(year, value, -id) %>% drop_na() %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(value = paste(value,collapse=" "))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `base R` method

```
input$ALL <- apply(input[-1], 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse=" "))
input$ALL
#[1] "tv"     "web"    "book"   "web tv"
```

Answer (score 4):

This actually is duplicate (or is really close) of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712390/how-do-i-remove-nas-with-the-tidyrunite-function) question but [things have changed since then](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/203). `unite` has `na.rm` parameter which helps to drop `NA`s.

As far as selection of columns is concerned, here we have selected all the columns ignoring the first one without specifying the column names so it should work for your case with multiple years.

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>%
    unite("ALL", names(input)[-1], remove = FALSE, sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  id    ALL    `2017` `2018` `2019`
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 aa    tv     tv     NA     NA    
#2 ss    web    NA     web    NA    
#3 dd    book   NA     NA     book  
#4 qq    web tv web    NA     tv
```

It worked for me after installing the development version of `tidyr` by doing

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")
```

Comment: Upvote for useful info, but still seems to me to not be a great way to structure data which is mostly `NA`. Particularly given the fact that the number of years present in a dataset will be unknown in advance.

Comment: @thelatemail That's true. Would you mind adding an answer with the `gather` approach ?

Comment: I think that would be a bit tangential as it doesn't answer the question as posed - there is an 'answer' of sorts in the comments above from me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Tidyverse 1.2.1 and cannot use na.rm in unite(). So the devtools tidyverse will be the next version of tidyr?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness (and to supplement [LocoGris' `data.table` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55215365/3817004)), there are three other approaches which update `input` *by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole data object.

All approaches return the same result and can handle an arbitrary number of years.

Note that `id` is supposed to be a unique key, i.e., without any duplicates.

#### Reshape, `na.omit()`, aggregate

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)[, ALL := melt(input, id.var = "id")[, toString(na.omit(value)), by = id]$V1][]
```

> ```
>    id 2017 2018 2019     ALL
> 1: aa   tv <NA> <NA>      tv
> 2: ss <NA>  web <NA>     web
> 3: dd <NA> <NA> book    book
> 4: qq  web <NA>   tv web, tv
> ```

BTW, reshaping from wide to long format exhibits a more concise way to store the sparsely populated data.

```
melt(input, id.var = "id", na.rm = TRUE)
```

> ```
>    id variable value
> 1: aa     2017    tv
> 2: qq     2017   web
> 3: ss     2018   web
> 4: dd     2019  book
> 5: qq     2019    tv
> ```

#### Reshape, aggregate, join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)[melt(input, id.var = "id", na.rm = TRUE)[, toString(value), by = id],
             on = "id", ALL := V1][]
```

This drops the `NA` values from the result of the reshape step which distorts the original row order due to the many `NA`. Hence, an *update join* is required.

#### `Filter()`, aggregate

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)[, ALL := .SD[, toString(Filter(Negate(is.na), .SD)), by = id]$V1][]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
input <- data.table(
  id = c('aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'qq'),
  '2017' = c('tv', NA, NA, 'web'),
  '2018' = c(NA, 'web', NA, NA),
  '2019' = c(NA, NA, 'book', 'tv')
)

""-> input[is.na(input)]
input[, ALL:=paste0(.SD,collapse=" "), .SDcols =2:length(input), by=seq_len(nrow(input))]
```