# Merge 3 columns based on unique values?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to do a merge on 3 columns to a single one. The column values are separated by ";" and the new column need to unzip all the 3 column values and put the unique values. I know how to perform the merge column. But I am struggling to do unzipping the row value in 3 columns and finding unique value and putting in another column.

Here is the dummy data

```
n = c(2, 3, 5,10) 
s = c("aa;bb;cc", "bb;dd;aa", "NA","xx;nn") 
b = c("aa;bb;cc", "bb;dd;cc", "zz;bb;yy","NA") 
t = c("aa;bb;cc", "bb;dd", "kk","NA") 
df = data.frame(n, s, b,t)

> df
   n        s        b        t
1  2 aa;bb;cc aa;bb;cc aa;bb;cc
2  3 bb;dd;aa bb;dd;cc    bb;dd
3  5       NA zz;bb;yy       kk
4 10    xx;nn       NA       NA
```

The expected output is

```
> df
   n  finalcol
1  2 aa;bb;cc
2  3 bb;dd;aa;cc
3  5 zz;bb;yy;kk
4 10 xx;nn
```

What I have to perform a simple merge

```
dff = df %>% unite(finalcol, c(s,b,t), sep = ";", remove = TRUE)
```

Comment: `apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x[!is.na(x)], ";"))), collapse = ";"))`

Comment: Thanks @d.b for jumping in. Here even NA is included and not part as a new column. What could I do ?

Comment: Figure out if you have `NA` or `"NA"`. The answer in the comments only works with `NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned `unite`, I want to show a solution using `separate`, the complement of `unite`.

This solution keeps it within the `tidyverse`, which makes it easy to understand what's going on step-by-step. @d.b's answer in the comment works perfectly, is compact, and probably runs faster, but has a steeper learning curve to understand what's going on. With a piped `tidyverse` solution, you can run each line and see what's going on.

This solution first `separate`s the terms, then converts the data from wide to long data format with `gather`, so that we can do operations such as check for and handle NAs and "NA"s, `drop_na`, and then `distinct`, to get unique values only (per group with the same "id" i.e. items from the same original line). Then, it uses `summarise` and `paste` to go back to the original format, but could also use `spread` then `unite`. (Note that `na.rm=TRUE` is an upcoming feature of `unite` https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/203)

Sources: I used these handy `dplyr` and `tidyr` reference sheets: 
https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/data-transformation.pdf
https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/data-import.pdf and I also worked out the solution based on the comments, questions, and answers here: [How do I remove NAs with the tidyr::unite function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712390/how-do-i-remove-nas-with-the-tidyrunite-function)

```r
# Load packages and data
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(n = c(2, 3, 5,10), 
                s = c("aa;bb;cc", "bb;dd;aa", "NA","xx;nn"),
                b = c("aa;bb;cc", "bb;dd;cc", "zz;bb;yy","NA"), 
                t = c("aa;bb;cc", "bb;dd", "kk", NA))

# Solution
dff <- df %>% 
  separate(col = "s", into = c("s1", "s2", "s3")) %>%
  separate(col = "b", into = c("b1", "b2", "b3")) %>%
  separate(col = "t", into = c("t1", "t2", "t3")) %>% # Solution here could be enhanced to take in n columns and put them into however many columns as needed, using map or apply. 
  rowid_to_column('id') %>% 
  gather(key, value, -(id:n)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(value), na_if, "NA") %>%
  drop_na(value) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  distinct(value, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(n = first(n), finalcol = paste(value, collapse = ';')) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id)
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [3,
#> 4].
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [4].
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [2,
#> 3].
dff
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       n finalcol   
#>   <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1     2 aa;bb;cc   
#> 2     3 bb;dd;aa;cc
#> 3     5 zz;bb;yy;kk
#> 4    10 xx;nn
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>