# Combining two columns in a dataframe without NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we have this:

```
  n       s     
1 Alabama NA 
2 New     Hampshire
3 New     York
```

and we wanted to combine the two columns into one without the NA value:

```
  n      
1 Alabama 
2 New Hampshire
3 New York
```

How would we go about doing that? I tried using paste() but it in turn also pasted in the NA value as `Alabama NA`. Please let me know!

Comment: Hard coded `base`: `data.frame(new_column=gsub("NA","",paste(df$n,df$s)))`

Comment: Probably, this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712390/how-do-i-remove-nas-with-the-tidyrunite-function/

Answer (score 2):

Try using `paste()` here with `coalesce`, from the `dplyr` package:

```
df$n <- paste(df$n, coalesce(df$s, ""))
```

We could also use `is.na` for a pure base R solution:

```
df$n <- paste(df$n, ifelse(is.na(df$s), "", df$s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Tidy approach:

```
df %>% tidyr::unite("n",n,s, sep = " ", na.rm = T) 
#edit: just noticed separator as "space".
```